# Difference between two time_point instances is not a duration?

Tags: c++, g++, c++-chrono

I don't understand why this code chokes with g++ 4.7.2:

```
#include <chrono>

main ()
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t1, t2 ;
    std::chrono::seconds delay ;

    t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::max () ;
    t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now () ;
    delay = t1 - t2 ;
    // t1 = t2 + delay ;
    // t1 = t2 - delay ;
}
```

with the error:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:10:18: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘delay = std::chrono::operator,<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > >((*(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > >*)(& t1)), (*(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > >*)(& t2)))’
```

It seemed to me that "time_point - time_point" gives a "duration".

Comment: Oh yeah, right, C++ compilers **still** suck at error messages.

Comment: @KonradRudolph library authors could greatly improve them with more liberal `static_assert` usage, I'm not sure why they don't.

Comment: @DavidBrown: You can't use `static_assert` to report whether a suitable function/operator overload exists. Concepts might help, but they don't exist yet.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you might be interested in camomilla https://github.com/SuperV1234/camomilla

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It does produce a duration, but there are different kinds of durations. [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) is templatized on a representation type and a unit ratio. `std::chrono::seconds` for example has a unit ratio of 1, while `std::chono::nanoseconds` has a unit ratio of `std::nano`, or 1/1000000000. time points have the same template parameters.

The specific unit ratio of `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` is implementation defined, but it is almost certainly less than than that of `std::chrono::seconds`. As such, the duration produced from subtracting those two time points has much more precision than can be represented by `std::chrono::seconds`.  The default behaviour is to not allow assignments that lose precision with durations that have integer representations. So you can either use a duration with enough precision (`std::chrono::system_clock::duration`) or cast the result to the duration you want (`std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(...)`).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. So, if I had used the std::chrono::nanoseconds type for the delay variable, I would have not noticed the problem, and I would have not learnt an important thing!

Comment: @pdagog `std::chrono::nanoseconds` is not necessarily going to work (at least not everywhere). `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` could be in nanoseconds, or it could be something even smaller. That's why you should use `std::chrono::system_clock::duration`.

Comment: Sure: I should have said "So, if I had used the std::chrono::nanoseconds type for the delay variable, _which appears to be the clock grain on my system_, I would have not noticed...". Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 5):

`time_point - time_point` does return a `duration`, just not the one in the code. You could replace `std::chrono::seconds` with `std::chrono::system_clock::duration`, or you could use a `duration_cast` to convert to the kind you need.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between two time points is indeed a duration; but you can't implicitly convert one duration type to another, since that could silently lose precision.

If you want to reduce the precision from `system_clock::duration` to `seconds`, then you need to make the conversion explicit using a `duration_cast`:

```
delay = duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t1 - t2);
```

Alternatively, you might want to retain the precision of the system clock:

```
auto delay = t1 - t2; // Probably microseconds, or nanoseconds, or something
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler does not allow you to convert to integer duration if there is possibility that the result of the conversion is a real number. You are using type `std::chrono::seconds` that is defined as `duration<*at least 35 bits integer*, ratio<1> >`.
Try to use duration with floating point instead:

```
duration<double, 1> delay; // or duration<double> delay;
delay = t1 - t2;
```

or some duration_cast as mentioned by others.